# Why doesn't this MongoDB connection work in a grunt script?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gruntjs

If I run this using node it prints "Connected to Database":

```
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/db1", function(err, db) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log("Connected to Database");
  db.close();
});
```

However if I try to run it with a Grunt task it does nothing and silently.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  return grunt.registerTask("task", "subtask", function() {
    var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
    return MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/db1", function(err, db) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      console.log("Connected to Database");
      db.close();
    });
  });
};
```

Can anyone tell me why this should be and perhaps provide a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything works as it should be.

Database connections are async and therefore grunt "kills off" you task before the connection is ever established.

You task should look like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  return grunt.registerTask("task", "subtask", function() {
    var done = this.async();
    var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/db1", function(err, db) {
      if (err) {
        done(false);
      }
      console.log("Connected to Database");
      db.close();
      done();
    });
  });
};
```

There is an entire section in the grunt documentation about this: [Why doesn't my asynchronous task complete?](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#why-doesn-t-my-asynchronous-task-complete)